# Как создать отчет с параметрами используя Microsoft Reporting Service через URL

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день.

Подскажите, где неправильно делаю.

Поднял сервер "http://frodo/BlackLabelReports" и создал один отчет "SystemMenu.rdl" на нем. В отчете есть текстовый параметр [@Contr](/users/959/control).

Версия: SQL Server 2012 Standart.

Через штатную смотрелку адрес отчета такой: http://frodo/BlackLabelReports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSystemMenu

Мне необходимо сформировать отчет через URL сразу в PDF. Параметр также надо задать через URL.

Делаю так:
http://frodo/BlackLabelReports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSystemMenu&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&Contr=Home

В итоге все равно открывается штатная смотрелка.

По советам с форумов пытался сделать так:

1 способ:
http://frodo/BlackLabelReports/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSystemMenu
Возвращает 404 ошибку.

2 способ:
http://frodo/BlackLabelReports?SystemMenu&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&Contr=Home
Перенаправляет на страницу: http://frodo/BlackLabelReports/Pages/Folder.aspx

Подскажите что можно сделать?

---

В общем, как обычно, как только написал вопрос - сразу нашелся и ответ.

Дело в том, что в качестве адреса сервиса я указывал адрес ReportManagerURL, а надо WEB Service URL. В моем случае вместо BlackLabelReports надо было указать BlackLabelReportServer.

Этот URL сделал все, что требуется:
http://frodo/BlackLabelReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSystemMenu&Contr=home&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF